# Open ground outlets with no power

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I have 7 outlets with an open ground and no power with a new breaker and the rest or my house reads open ground on my outlets and they all have power. What do I do where do i start?

Comment: You start by revising to give us more information. How old is the house? Have you ever checked ground at the outlets before? Who did the breaker replacement and why? It's tough to diagnose through the internet without a clearer picture of the problem.

Comment: the house is only 3 years old. I checked it with a 3 prog tester and a voltage tester.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear what "no power with a new breaker" means. Please _revise your question_ to provide more clarity.

Comment: Is this a breaker with a reset on it? Are there lights on the breaker, have you pressed the test then the reset? I would guess at 3 years old you have a bad tester or the bonding jumper from neutral to ground in the main panel is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the beginning:  do you have a solid connection to a copper earth rod at your incoming breaker-box? The 'rest of my house reads open ground' is indicative of a problem at your main. Sounds to me like you have described a complete absence of an earth-ground for your home.

Comment: Those testers cannot tell if there is a true ground or not. A main panel has the ground and neutral tied together. At only 3 years old there is a bigger problem like no bonding jumper in the panel.